# VBA Form Returning the WEEKNUM

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a VBA user form to show the week number on the data sheet.

So for example. when the form is submitted it creates the date of when the button is pressed. I need that to also show the week number against that date when the button is pressed.

I have tried a similar call function when using date and changed to weeknumber and i have checked online but I am struggling to find the answer.

```
Dim emptyRow As Long, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Ethan")
emptyRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


ws.Range("A" & emptyRow).Value = Date
ws.Range("A" & emptyRow).Value = WeekNum (this doesn't work)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use the WEEKNUM function in a statement in VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38282079/how-can-i-use-the-weeknum-function-in-a-statement-in-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ws.Range("A" & emptyRow).Value = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Date, vbMonday)`